# PHP Array to JavaScript Length

Tags: javascript, php

I wrote this code:

```
$userAddresses = $database->getUsers("SELECT * FROM Users");

$address = array();
foreach($userAddresses as $user){
    array_push($address, array("address"=> $user['address'],
                               "zipcode" => $user['zipcode']));
}
$locations = array(
            "locations" => $address
);

$jsonLocations = json_encode($locations);
```

This code returns this json object:

```
{"locations":[
             {"address":"Sneekermeer 25","zipcode":"2993 RL"},
             {"address":"Boeier 13","zipcode":"2992 AK"}]}
```

I want to get the length of this array inside JavaScript. So I did this:

```
var address = '<?php echo $jsonLocations ?>';
```

After that I called `console.log(address.length);` to check the length but some how it counts all the chars (108 I think) in the address variable and returns that as length. `address.locations.length` also doesn't work.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: what do you mean by length? what it should be showed?

Comment: Note the quotes on your address line. It's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var address = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonLocations ?>');

console.log(address.length); //  will give you length;
```

Comment: If you go this route, you have to double-encode it, see @Geoffrey's post.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the string needs to be decoded to an object. You can do this one of two ways.

Non recommended:

`var address = <?= $jsonLocations ?>;`

Or more correctly and safer:

`var address = JSON.parse('<?= addslashes(json_encode($jsonLocations)) ?>');`

Do not forget the call to `addslashes` to prevent any single quotes in your array from breaking the javascript string.

Comment: What's wrong with the first method? Looks better (and safer) to me.

Comment: @georg It can be used to inject Javascript, not just an object, where as the `JSON.parse` method will not execute any Javascript, but just load the object. It is why it exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the quotes around `var address = '<?php echo $jsonLocations ?>';` (i.e `var address = <?php echo $jsonLocations ?>;`) or use `JSON.parse` to parse it as a string to an object.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the below and its working

```
var address = '{"locations":[{"address":"Sneekermeer 25","zipcode":"2993 RL"},{"address":"Boeier 13","zipcode":"2992 AK"}]}';
address = JSON.parse(address);
console.log(address.locations.length);
```